# How to find the index of a tensor in a list?

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to find the index of the smallest tensor (by some key function) in a list `li`.
So I did `min` and afterwards `li.index(min_el)`. My MWE suggests that somehow tensors don't work with `index`.

```
import torch
li=[torch.ones(1,1), torch.zeros(2,2)]
li.index(li[0])
0
li.index(li[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File ".../local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 330, in __eq__
    return self.eq(other)
RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor size at /b/wheel/pytorch-src/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:2679
```

I can of course make my own index function that first checks for size and then element wise. E.g.

```
def index(list, element):
    for i,el in enumerate(list):
        if el.size() == element.size():
            diff = el - element
            if (1- diff.byte()).all():
               return i
    return -1
```

I was just wondering, why doesn't `index` work? 
Is there maybe a smart way of doing this not by hand that I'm missing?

Comment: Comparing two tensors returns a tensor, which has no reasonable conversion to `bool`. The interesting question is why it _doesn't_ fail for index 0. I tested it and it's the index, not the specific tensor, that makes it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly find the index by using `enumerate` and a key function that operates on the second element of each tuple. For instance, if your key function compares the first element of the each tensor, you could use

```
ix, _ = min(enumerate(li), key=lambda x: x[1][0, 0])
```

I think the reason why `index` succeeds for the first element is that Python probably does something that is equivalent to `x is value or x == value`, where `x` is the current element in the list. Since `value is value`, the failing equality comparison never happens. This is why `li.index(li[0])` works but this fails:

```
y = torch.ones(1,1)
li.index(y)
```